# How to increase map resolution

Tags: qgis, resolution

I see a number of posts about changing the resolution of an output of a map; however, my problem is that the map itself is lacking in adequate resolution. When working in the main QGIS program, I can zoom in and see much detail in my underlying aerial photo. However, when I make a map using Print Composer, I cannot zoom in without losing too much resolution. It becomes pixillated.

I have tried increasing the size of the map, but that doesn't seem to make any difference. My properties are set to "render", not "cache". Under "Variables\Composition\layout_dpi" it is 300; but I can't seem to change that, or don't know how.

Comment: Have you tried clicking - Export as PNG Image, and one could change the values of dpi there. I haven't had a problem with resolution so far.

Comment: That does seem to work! I thought it wouldn't because it appeared to be lacking in the source, so how could it be better after exporting?

Comment: Keep in mind that print composer is just a preview, and doesn't show all the detail available in the map. To increase the amount of detail displayed after zooming in on the composer, you must refresh the display. Use the "refresh view" button in the navigation toolbar to refresh the whole composer, or refresh an individual composer item using the "update preview" button in the item properties panel.

Comment: @Vijay Ramesh - Probably posting your comment as an answer to TVZ can accept it

Comment: Thank you. I did not understand that about the preview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try selecting - Export as PNG Image, and one could change the values of dpi there.

In addition as CSK mentioned in the comments, the Print composer is just a preview does not show all the detail available in the map. Use the "refresh view" button in the navigation toolbar to refresh the whole composer, or refresh an individual composer item using the "update preview" button in the item properties panel.

In addition, one could vary the value of the scale, instead of using the cursor to zoom in and out. I find that to be much more effective and less error free. And of course, lock the map items to prevent any additional change if you are adding an inset etc.